# Using Cypress Component Testing with a NextJS application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, cypress

I think I need a little help on how to use the cypress plugin for **nextJS** in order to run [Cypress Components Test](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/introduction#Install)

> package.json

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/react": "^5.3.4",
    "@cypress/webpack-dev-server": "^1.1.4",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.7.0",
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^7.0.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.36",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "cypress": "^7.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
```

> cypress/plugins/index.ts

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require('@cypress/react/plugins/next')(on, config)

  return config
}
```

Trying to start the test throws a `options.rewrites.map is not a function` error

```sh
$ yarn cypress open-ct
yarn run v1.22.5
$ /Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/node_modules/.bin/cypress open-ct
info  - Loaded env from /Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/.env.local
Error [TypeError]: options.rewrites.map is not a function
    at new BuildManifestPlugin (/Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/node_modules/next/build/webpack/plugins/build-manifest-plugin.ts:94:38)
    at getBaseWebpackConfig (/Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/node_modules/next/build/webpack-config.ts:1133:9)
    at getNextWebpackConfig (/Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/node_modules/@cypress/react/plugins/next/findNextWebpackConfig.js:9:29)
    at findNextWebpackConfig (/Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/node_modules/@cypress/react/plugins/next/findNextWebpackConfig.js:36:24)
    at Object.handler (/Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/node_modules/@cypress/react/plugins/next/index.js:5:27)
TypeError: options.rewrites.map is not a function
    at new BuildManifestPlugin (/Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/node_modules/next/build/webpack/plugins/build-manifest-plugin.ts:94:38)
    at getBaseWebpackConfig (/Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/node_modules/next/build/webpack-config.ts:1133:9)
    at getNextWebpackConfig (/Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/node_modules/@cypress/react/plugins/next/findNextWebpackConfig.js:9:29)
    at findNextWebpackConfig (/Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/node_modules/@cypress/react/plugins/next/findNextWebpackConfig.js:36:24)
    at Object.handler (/Users/norfeldt/Repos/LoCali/locali-web/node_modules/@cypress/react/plugins/next/index.js:5:27)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Got the same issue trying to develop the Storybook plugin. Rewrites is no using an object but I don't get why the BuildManifestPlugin does'nt check for it.

Comment: @EricBurel I posted an answer. It it works for you then give et a vote.

Comment: It seems that it's related to some mismatching version, by updating Next it works again for me (I am using a local install of Canary branch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a working solution on [cypress discussion](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/discussions/16136#discussioncomment-678928)

Just gonna dump what made it work for me

Updated NextJS to the latest version.

Then I also did

```sh
yarn add -D cypress @cypress/webpack-dev-server @cypress/react html-webpack-plugin@4 webpack@4 webpack-dev-server
```

> ./tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["*"]
    },
    "types": ["cypress", "@testing-library/cypress"]
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

> ./cypress/tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["../**/*.ts*"]
}
```

```
// ./cypress/plugins/index.ts
const injectDevServer = require('@cypress/react/plugins/next')

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  injectDevServer(on, config)
  return config
}
```

(Bonus to get **testing library** commands baked into cypress)

```sh
yarn add -D @testing-library/cypress
```

```
// ./cypress/support/index.ts
/// <reference types="cypress" />

import '@testing-library/cypress/add-commands'
```

```
// ./components/Dishcard/index.spec.tsx
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from '@cypress/react'

import DishCard from '.'
import { DishesProvider } from '~/context/dishes'
import { CartProvider } from '~/context/cart'

describe('DishCard', () => {
  it('looks great', () => {
    mount(
      <CartProvider>
        <DishesProvider>
          <DishCard id="dish02" />
        </DishesProvider>
      </CartProvider>
    )
    cy.findByText('CHICKEN', { exact: false })
  })
})
```

[image: screenshot of working solution]